# Java can't do system call

Tags: java, java-8

I am using Java  to format a poem in LaTeX and then compile it. The LaTeX-ization works perfectly fine, but I somehow can't run the command. Is this a problem with my LaTeX invocation? For some reason, when I use Java to write an equivalent batch file and then run it, Java will do nothing but when I run the batch file from the shell, it works.

```
    /**
     *
     * @param title the title of the poem
     * @param poem a <code>List</code> with one string for each line of the
     * poem.
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     */
    protected static void writePDF(final String title, List<String> poem) throws FileNotFoundException {
    final StringBuilder latex = new StringBuilder(0);
    // I know I shouldn't concatenate like this; I'll fix it later.
    // eeeewww escapes
    latex.append(
        "\\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,article,oneside]{memoir}\n"
        + "\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\n"
        + "\\usepackage{ebgaramond}\n"
        + "\\usepackage{hyperref}\n"
        + "\\usepackage[protrusion,expansion,kerning,tracking,spacing]{microtype}\n"
        + "\\linespread{1.3}\n"
        + "\\nonfrenchspacing\n"
        + "\\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}\n"
        + "\\begin{document}\n"
        + "\\title{" + title + "}\n"
        + "\\author{}\n"
        + "\\date{\\today}\n"
        + "\\maketitle\n"
        + "\\setlength{\\parindent}{0pt}\n"
        + "\\setlength{\\parskip}{\\baselineskip}\n");
    // Go Java 8!
    poem
        .stream()
        .map((String s)
            // Original poem's in HTML
            -> s.replace("<p>", "\n\n").replace("<br>", "\\\\\n"))
        .forEach(latex::append);
    latex.append("\n\\end{document}");
    final String latexstr = latex.toString().replace("...", "\\ldots");
    final String filename = title + ".tex";
    final File file = new File(filename);
    try (final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)))) {
        pw.print(latexstr);
    }
    final String path = file.getAbsolutePath()
        .substring(0, file.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("\\")) + "\\";
    System.out.println("Path: " + path);

    final String LaTeXcmd = "pdflatex \""
        + path
        + title + "\"";
    final File script = new File(""
        + rand.nextDouble()
        + "compile"
        + title.replace(" ", "_")
        + ".bat");
//I originally wanted just to write a batch file and run it from Java.
//  try (final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(script)))) {
//      pw.print(""
//          //"@echo off\n"
//          + "cd " + path + "\n"
//          + LaTeXcmd + "\n"
//          //          + "del \"" + path + title + ".aux\"\n"
//          //          + "del \"" + path + title + ".log\"\n"
//          //          + "del \"" + path + title + ".out\"\n"
//          //          + "del \"" + path + title + ".tex\"\n"
//          //          + "start /b \"\" cmd /c del \"%~f0\"&exit /b\n"
//
//          + "msg * all\n"
//      );
//  }
    try {
        System.out.println("latexcmd " + LaTeXcmd);
        final File workingdir = new File(path);
        System.out.println("workingdir " + workingdir);
// >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> IS THIS CORRECT? <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(LaTeXcmd, new String[]{}, workingdir);
// This statement works perfectly fine (Windows).
//      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("msg * all");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PoetryBackend.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    }
```

Comment: Please remove all the redundant code. You are asking about making the system call, so why you are messing the question with all the other things? Your LaTex code and most other code is completely irrelevant for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not correct. Try

```
String command = new String[] {"cmd", "/c", LaTeXcmd };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, new String[]{}, workingdir);
```

since otherwise you're not executing it through command interpreter, which is what you want if you want it to behave like you would run it from cmd prompt.

This applies to running .bat files as well.